# Find if a pattern matches then outputting split data from another column - $|$ separator failure

Tags: python, pandas, split, series

As part of a longer code, I reached a roadblock when trying to do the following:
I have a library of 3 columns: [ClusterID, Human, Mouse]

```
ClusterID   Human   Mouse
50  LongAUGORFlinc|3P|XLOC_076196|TCONS_00295623:0.269513|182AA|167AA|$|$linc|3P|XLOC_037932|TCONS_00153577:0.957089|101AA|56AA|$|$linc|3P|XLOC_048756|TCONS_00195334:1.35817|128AA|73AA|   linc|3P|XLOC_066319|TCONS_00127223:1.0925|85AA|41AA|$|$LongAUGORFEnsASCoding|3P|XLOC_104581|TCONS_00206607|Nr2f2:0.354897|174AA|162AA||RNACodeAS|HSS_32160_5.3E-14$HSS_32161_6.4E-9$HSS_32163_3.9E-11$HSS_32164_6.5E-6$HSS_32165_4.7E-6$HSS_32166_1.7E-7$HSS_32168_8.1E-6$HSS_32169_3.2E-8$|$LongAUGORFEnsASCoding|3P|XLOC_113060|TCONS_00223512|Sugp1:1.20904|141AA|141AA||RNACodeAS|NearGap
81  EnsASCoding|3P|XLOC_034831|TCONS_00142998:0.399276|92AA|83AA|$|$LongAUGORFlinc|3P|XLOC_033946|TCONS_00137705:0.986858|221AA|196AA|$|$EnsASCoding|3P|XLOC_000485|TCONS_00003136:0.4139|122AA|78AA||RNACodeAS|HSS_0_4.2E-9$HSS_1_4.5E-5$|$EnsASCoding|3P|XLOC_034831|TCONS_00142998:0.399276|92AA|83AA|   linc|3P|XLOC_104529|TCONS_00206387:0.585795|114AA|82AA|$|$EnsASCoding|3P|XLOC_082328|TCONS_00160013:0.608952|88AA|59AA||RNACodeAS|HSS_18226_2.7E-14$HSS_18230_7.0E-5$HSS_18231_3.8E-13$HSS_18232_1.4E-5$|$LongAUGORFEnsASCoding|3P|XLOC_097111|TCONS_00191837|Zfp422:0.683284|252AA|192AA||RNACodeAS|HSS_28462_1.1E-12$HSS_28463_1.0E-16
279 linc|3P|XLOC_067039|TCONS_00267121:3.78124|173AA|31AA|$|$linc|3P|XLOC_067039|TCONS_00267116:3.53265|56AA|54AA|$|$linc|3P|XLOC_067039|TCONS_00267119:0.429515|42AA|31AA|$|$inc|3P|XLOC_067039|TCONS_00267121:3.78124|173AA|31AA| LongAUGORFlinc|3P|XLOC_097853|TCONS_00194306|AB041803:0.416568|171AA|166AA|$|$LongAUGORFlinc|3P|XLOC_097853|TCONS_00194302|AB041803:0.682355|197AA|166AA|$|$LongAUGORFlinc|3P|XLOC_097853|TCONS_00194307|AB041803:0.181415|171AA|166AA|
```

Each element of column 2 and 3 are split by "$|$". However, there may be redundant portions in between $|$. For instance, in Human column 2nd row the following expression is repeated twice:

```
EnsASCoding|3P|XLOC_034831|TCONS_00142998:0.399276|92AA|83AA|
```

is repeated twice.

I have a query list of 2 columns: [GeneID, XLOC_ID]:

```
GeneID  XLOC_ID
A   LongAUGORFlinc|3P|XLOC_097853|TCONS_00194307|AB041803:0.181415|171AA|166AA|
B   linc|3P|XLOC_105908|TCONS_00210845:3.79119|120AA|90AA|
C   linc|3P|XLOC_082473|TCONS_00160364:0.170433|40AA|22AA|
D   LongAUGORFEnsASCoding|3P|XLOC_084529|TCONS_00166880:0.478235|183AA|171AA|
E   linc|3P|XLOC_043879|TCONS_00084901:2.01255|106AA|97AA|
```

Each row element of the query list is unique.

I want to look at the second column of the query list, look if the value matches any '$|$' separated element of the "Mouse" column of the library. If it does, then split the 'Human' column of the Library by "$|$" and then output each query id and each of the elements in $|$.

For instance,  XLOC_ID of "GeneID" A is: LongAUGORFlinc|3P|XLOC_097853|TCONS_00194307|AB041803:0.181415|171AA|166AA|

This is part of [row 3, Mouse column] of the Library. Hence, I need to split the Human column of row 3 by $|$ to output each on a separate line, such as result would be:

```
GeneID  XLOC_ID Human_ID
A   LongAUGORFlinc|3P|XLOC_097853|TCONS_00194307|AB041803:0.181415|171AA|166AA| linc|3P|XLOC_067039|TCONS_00267121:3.78124|173AA|31AA|
A   LongAUGORFlinc|3P|XLOC_097853|TCONS_00194307|AB041803:0.181415|171AA|166AA| linc|3P|XLOC_067039|TCONS_00267116:3.53265|56AA|54AA|
A   LongAUGORFlinc|3P|XLOC_097853|TCONS_00194307|AB041803:0.181415|171AA|166AA| linc|3P|XLOC_067039|TCONS_00267119:0.429515|42AA|31AA|
```

and do the same for rest of the query list, and all should be output in the same file.

Here is my code (I dont think it is the best in terms of memory, but it works):

```
library=pd.read_table("Library.txt")
mouse_lib=pd.Series(library['Mouse']).str.split("$|$")


dict1={}
human_lib=pd.Series(library['Human'].str.split("$|$"))
for index, value in human_lib.iteritems():
    k,v=index, human_lib[index]
    dict1[k]=v


out_match=open("Matching.xls", "w")

query=pd.read_table("Query.txt")
for i in range(0, len(query.index)):
    xloc=query.ix[i,"XLOC_ID"]
    for index, value in mouse_lib.iteritems():
        #print mouse_lib[index]
        if xloc in mouse_lib[index]:
            for value in dict1[index]:
                newline= query.ix[i,"GeneID-gtf"], xloc, str(value)
                out_match.write('\t'.join(newline)+'\n')
```

Unfortunately, the codes does NOT work if i have '$|$' as separator. If i replace all "$|$"  in all my input files with any other string such as "ZZZYYY" the script works then. I can't figure out why is that the case and i tried to search whether '$|$' is a predefined python code but i didn't find anything as such. Further, I am not sure if my code above is the best in terms of memory and power. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try escaping the symbols?

Comment: "$|$" is not a predefined Python code.  Have you checked the PANDAS documentation for same?

Comment: @DavidScottIV how can i escape symbols? My experience with regex and such things s quite limited and the above was my first script that involves such a thing. Any comment on the script iteration/memory?

Comment: @Prune I checked by google whether $|$ is in anyway associated with pandas python and didn't find anything.

Comment: From the research I just did, I suspect that the problem is only one of the characters, and that you may be able to solve it by following instructions for CSV files under PANDAS.  Have you tried printing the input *before* the split?  That would reduce the search space.  The split is not the problem; I just did one in Python 2.7, and it's quite happy with the "$|$" separator.

Comment: @Prune The input prints well before the split. In fact, when i try to print the first part of the splitting , i.e. using str.get(0), it prints the WHOLE line, if i  trying str.get(1) i.e. to find the second part of the split, i get "NaN" indicating that the split did not take place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot split by `$|$`, because it is used as regular expression - see [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html). You need escape it to `\$\|\$`.

First you can [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Then you can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for creating one column for matching. Then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) `Series` `mouse_lib` and `human_lib` together and merging by [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html). Last you can write `out` [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
#if separator is not ',' use sep=";" for ';' or sep="\s+" for whitespace
library = pd.read_csv("Library.txt")
query = pd.read_csv("Query.txt")


mouse_lib = library['Mouse'].str.split(r"\$\|\$", expand=True).stack()
human_lib= library['Human'].str.split("\$\|\$", expand=True).stack()

df = pd.concat([human_lib, mouse_lib], axis=1, keys=['human','mouse']).reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
```

```
print df
                                               human  \
0  LongAUGORFlinc|3P|XLOC_076196|TCONS_00295623:0...   
0  linc|3P|XLOC_037932|TCONS_00153577:0.957089|10...   
0  linc|3P|XLOC_048756|TCONS_00195334:1.35817|128...   
1  EnsASCoding|3P|XLOC_034831|TCONS_00142998:0.39...   
1  LongAUGORFlinc|3P|XLOC_033946|TCONS_00137705:0...   
1  EnsASCoding|3P|XLOC_000485|TCONS_00003136:0.41...   
1  EnsASCoding|3P|XLOC_034831|TCONS_00142998:0.39...   
2  linc|3P|XLOC_067039|TCONS_00267121:3.78124|173...   
2  linc|3P|XLOC_067039|TCONS_00267116:3.53265|56A...   
2  linc|3P|XLOC_067039|TCONS_00267119:0.429515|42...   
2  inc|3P|XLOC_067039|TCONS_00267121:3.78124|173A...   

                                               mouse  
0  linc|3P|XLOC_066319|TCONS_00127223:1.0925|85AA...  
0  LongAUGORFEnsASCoding|3P|XLOC_104581|TCONS_002...  
0  LongAUGORFEnsASCoding|3P|XLOC_113060|TCONS_002...  
1  linc|3P|XLOC_104529|TCONS_00206387:0.585795|11...  
1  EnsASCoding|3P|XLOC_082328|TCONS_00160013:0.60...  
1  LongAUGORFEnsASCoding|3P|XLOC_097111|TCONS_001...  
1                                                NaN  
2  LongAUGORFlinc|3P|XLOC_097853|TCONS_00194306|A...  
2  LongAUGORFlinc|3P|XLOC_097853|TCONS_00194302|A...  
2  LongAUGORFlinc|3P|XLOC_097853|TCONS_00194307|A...  
2                                                NaN
```

```
out =  pd.merge(df, query , left_on=['mouse'], right_on=['XLOC_ID']) 
print out
                                               human  \
0  linc|3P|XLOC_067039|TCONS_00267119:0.429515|42...   

                                               mouse GeneID  \
0  LongAUGORFlinc|3P|XLOC_097853|TCONS_00194307|A...      A   

                                             XLOC_ID  
0  LongAUGORFlinc|3P|XLOC_097853|TCONS_00194307|A...  

out.to_xls("Matching.xls")
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait a moment ... let's look at the splitting command:

```
mouse_lib=pd.Series(library['Mouse']).str.split("$|$")
```

You create a PANDAS series, and then apply the split to the *series*.  What does it mean to split a NDFrame?

I think you need to split the input and make a series out of that, neh?

Comment: It does not matter ( I guess ? ) because it works fine when data is split by ZZZYYY using the exact same command. Also, because it was my first time writing such a code with splitting and 'series', I simply used what other people posted on SO in other posts ... it was starting with the series, then splitting.